# Write file to Azure Web App from Azure Function?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

Is it possible for an Azure Function to write a file to an Azure Web App?

Currently, I'm having the Function write to a storage account, and then having the Web App pull down the file from there, but it would be much easier if I could just write to the Web App directly.

Comment: how you are getting the file into the AF, as a stream or?

Comment: @StronglyTyped, any update on this issue? Could you upload file with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You could only use the [ftp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp#get-ftp-connection-information) or the [kudu rest api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) to access the web files. The below is my test code upload a file from function to azure web wwwroot folder. You could use this code as a reference.

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string filepath = context.FunctionDirectory + "\\test.txt";

            sendmail("ftpusername", "ftpuserpassword", "ftphost/site/wwwroot/test.txt",filepath);


        }

        public static void sendmail(String name, String pass,String ftpadd,String filepath) {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpadd);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;


            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(name, pass);

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            byte[] fileContents;
            using (StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(filepath))
            {
                fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            }

            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            }

            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Upload File Complete, status {response.StatusDescription}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, it was possible to persist files to Web App Local storage. Now, Microsoft says:

> Although an app has full read/write access to its own temporary local
>   storage, that storage really isn't intended to be used directly by the
>   application code. Rather, the intent is to provide temporary file
>   storage for IIS and web application frameworks. App Service also
>   limits the amount of temporary local storage available to each app to
>   prevent individual apps from consuming excessive amounts of local file
>   storage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/operating-system-functionality

If it's being an expensive task, what you can do is include Redis Cache, and send the file to Redis and pull it from it on Web App.